# How to get location.href from external window object?

Tags: javascript, object, window, external

This is my example code to print esternal window location after 5sec:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function Loaded()
{
    var newPage=window.open('http://externaldomainurl','myWindow');
    newPage.focus();
    setTimeout(function(){urlCheck(newPage)}, 5000);
}

function urlCheck(newPage)
{
    alert(newPage.location)
    newPage.close();
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:Loaded();">TEST</a>
```

But nothing appear on alert.

Tnks

Comment: Welcome to [so].  So that we can answer your question more clearly and you can learn more from your problems, we need more information.  What have you done to attempt to solve the issue?  Does anything appear on the console when you open your page/run the code?  These sorts of things needs to be provided for us to answer your questions better, and also to be well regarded within the community.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Access to data on other origins is restricted for security reasons. You can't monitor where a user has browsed to after they leave your site.

You can use [`postMessage` and `addEventListener('message', listener)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to pass messages between the two origins if you are able to edit the code for both of them.